# Team viewer on Macbook Pro with Cinema Display

Tags: remote-desktop, macbook, teamviewer

I've been using team viewer to render files when I'm not at my office. I alternate between two macbook pros, mid 2012, one with retina display and one without.

When I have either of these laptops connected to a cinema display via thunderbolt, I am able to remote login via team viewer without any issues. However, after I close the session, I am unable to start a new one. Each time I try, I first see the login-page from my computer, and after I login, I get a black screen.

I investigated the issue by using team viewer with both computers in front of me. What I noticed was that after I closed a remote session and locked the computer, the screen would go black and stay black (computer A). Even when on my remote computer (B) with team viewer open I could see the login page when A was still black.

So, I tried disconnecting the monitors and am still having a funky issue. I am able to login to A from B for multiple sessions, but after the first time I lock A its screen will stay black. In order to use A without Teamviewer I now need to re-start it.

Any tips?